How to Implement Markup and Annotation Tools for Drawings in a Flutter Application?
Background:
We are developing a project folder management feature in our Flutter application, specifically focusing on handling drawings. This includes implementing markup and annotation tools for drawings, with capabilities such as adding comments, highlighting areas, and drawing shapes. Additionally, we need to support version control to track changes and maintain file history.
Requirements:

Annotation Tools:

Comments: Users should be able to add text comments on the drawings.

Highlighting: Users should be able to highlight specific areas of the drawings.

Shapes: Users should be able to draw shapes like rectangles, circles, and freehand lines.



Version Control:

File History: Maintain a history of changes made to the drawings.
Revert Changes: Allow users to revert to previous versions of the drawings.



Question:
How can we implement markup and annotation tools for drawings in a Flutter application? Specifically, I am looking for guidance on:

Adding text comments on drawings.
Highlighting specific areas on
drawings.
Drawing shapes (rectangles, circles, freehand lines) on
drawings.
Implementing version control to maintain and revert file
history.

We want to achieve functionalities similar to the ones described in this link:
https://support.procore.com/products/online/user-guide/project-level/drawings/tutorials/mark-up-a-drawing.
Notes:

The drawings can be PDF files or images.
The drawings can be huge, so the user might want to zoom in significantly.
We need the markups and annotations to be saved to the file itself, whether it's a PDF or an image.
It would be perfect if we can implement something exactly like the provided URL.

